# ¿Por qué no se ven choices desde models.py en el template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

una duda, ¿ustedes saben como pasar las opciones de un select desde forms.py?
Resulta que hice un modelo en la app de clientes, luego lo pasé al form de la app de clientes, lo heredé en otro form de una app que se llama presupuestos, y al presentarlo en el template sólo se ve el campo vacío sin las opciones

> models.py (de la app de clientes)

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
    TITLE=(
        ('Mrs.','Mrs.'),
        ('Miss','Miss'),
        ('Mr.','Mr.'),
    )
    titulo=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,choices=TITLE)
    nombre =models.CharField(max_length=80)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}:{self.titulo}{self.nombre}'
```

> forms.py (de la app de clientes)

```
class ClientesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Clientes
        fields=['titulo','nombre']
```

> forms.py (de la app de presupuesto que hereda de forms.py de la app de clientes)

```
class PresupuestosClientesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clientes
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'titulo': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-select'
                }
            ),
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            ),
         }
```

> en el template presupuestos-form.html donde no se ven las opciones reflejadas

```
<label for="titulo" id="titulo">Título</label>
{{presupuestosclientesform.titulo}}
<select class="form-select">
           <option>Elige</option>
           <option>Mrs.</option>
           <option>Miss</option>
           <option>Mr.</option>
</select>
```

> views.py (de la app de clientes)

```
def create_Clientes(request):
    form=ClientesForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('clientes:index')
    return render(request,'clientes/clientes-form.html',{'form':form})
```

> views.py (de la app de presupuestos)

```
def create_Presupuestos(request):
    presupuestosclientesform=PresupuestosClientesForm(request.POST or None)
    presupuestosvehiculosform=PresupuestosVehiculosForm(request.POST or None)
    presupuestosparteform=PresupuestosParteForm(request.POST or None)
    presupuestosmanoobraform=PresupuestosManoObraForm(request.POST or None)
    presupuestospagosform=PresupuestosPagosForm(request.POST or None)

    if presupuestosclientesform.is_valid():
        presupuestosclientesform.save()
        return redirect('presupuestos:index')
    return render(request,'Presupuestos/presupuestos-forms.html',{'presupuestosclientesform':presupuestosclientesform,'presupuestosvehiculosform':presupuestosvehiculosform, 'presupuestosparteform':presupuestosparteform, 'presupuestosmanoobraform':presupuestosmanoobraform,'presupuestospagosform':presupuestospagosform})
```

Comment: y la vista, sybela

Comment: listo, ya actualicé la info